# ASP.Net MVC: Store data in OnActionExecuting and retrieve it in OnActionExecuted in a controller

Tags: performance, model-view-controller, session

I want to add some code to log the time spent in each action call in a controller. I saw a suggestion of creating a Stopwatch inside the OnActionExecuting method of the controller and stoping it OnActionExecuted, which seems fine to me.

What I want to know is where do I have to add the started Stopwatch object so it can be read back once OnActionExecuted is called. 
I was thinking on adding it to the Session, but I'm guessing this might have issues if there are simultaneous requests from the same session.

What is the best place to store this data?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use HttpContext.Current.Items for objects that are related to a single request.

https://web.archive.org/web/20201202215202/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/060904-1.aspx